# Thingsboard Map Widget configuration

Tags: thingsboard

I tried to create a Map Widget by selecting data from device. Then, it was unclear on the "Settings" and "Advanced" tabs of the Map widget. There's no documentation on the Map widget,either.

When using Openstreet or Terrain-Google Map, how to pinpoint a location address and then drill down to a specific place and show the locations's telemetry data and attributes?

Can somebody share the details, please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thingsboard posted videos on how to use Maps and other stuff, too.

Excellent, this answered my question.

Link :

[Thingsboard Dashbaord development using Maps](https://youtu.be/BhYnKtbUHHI)

Comment: Hi, How to redirect to custome login page to thingsboard.io/home using auth/login API, Please if you have knowledge can you share with us.

Comment: sorry, havent done that yet. try gitter chat. Andrew might respond!!

Comment: The video is unavailable, which is one reason link-only answers are not useful.